# How to vertically align 2 classes inside div

Tags: css

I have a wrapper including some info div's inside. All things are well, But i can't make it vertically justified.

How to justify vertically aligned and positioned in the middle both .title & .text classes?

```css
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width:96.4%;
    height:80%;
    border:1px solid #1f1e1e;
    padding:10px;
}
.info{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:32%;
    background-color:#1b1f1e;
    border-radius:6px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
 }
.title{
    background-color:#dc6210;
    text-align:center;
    height:50%;
    line-height:50%;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
 }
.text{
    text-align:center;
    height:50%;
    line-height: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="info">
     <div class="title">Title</div>
     <div class="text"> "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." </div>     
  </div>
  <div class="info">
     <div class="title">Title</div>
     <div class="text"> "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="info">
     <div class="title">Title</div>
     <div class="text"> "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:before` to help vertical alignment, and remove the `line-height: 50%;`.

```
.info > div:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```css
body {margin-left: 0px;margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;}
#wrapper {width:96.4%;height:80%; border:1px solid #1f1e1e; padding:10px;}
.info{width:100%;height:32%;background-color:#1b1f1e; border-radius:6px;color:#fff;font-size:18px;margin-bottom:6px;}
.title{background-color:#dc6210;text-align:center;height:50%;border-top-left-radius:6px;border-top-right-radius:6px;}
.text{text-align:center;height:50%;}

#wrapper{
  min-height: 400px;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 98%;
}
.info > div:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="info">
 <div class="title">Title</div>
 <div class="text">
 <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>
 </div>     
  </div>
  <div class="info">
 <div class="title">Title</div>
 <div class="text">
 <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>
 </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="info">
 <div class="title">Title</div>
 <div class="text">
 <p>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3rj01sp2/1/

Comment: Fiddle updated with a `p` tag. [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3rj01sp2/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3rj01sp2/1/)

Comment: Felix is there any way to achieve this without the html and body declarations?

The wrapper will be displayed inside another div and cannot change my html and body css settings..

html, body removed and #wrapper height chenged to height:80vh;
That's worked but is the correct solution?

Comment: content: ''; inside info > div:before removed too cause when resizing horizontally the first div, text moves to next div and displayed empty...

Answer (score 2):

**Update Css**

```
.title {
    background-color: #dc6210;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;

}

.text {
    text-align: center;
    padding:16px;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/7Lzgux74/)

**Notes:** remove your `height:50%;line-height: 50%;`  and Add padding

Comment: Thanks Sumit but when resizing window text disappeared. I want both div sections  stay visible....
That's i use height ..